# Struggling with ASP.NET MVC auto-scaffolder template

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, templates

I'm trying to write an auto-scaffolder template for Index views. I'd like to be able to pass in a collection of models or view-models (e.g., `IQueryable<MyViewModel>`) and get back an HTML table that uses the `DisplayName` attribute for the headings (`th` elements) and `Html.Display(propertyName)`  for the cells (`td` elements). Each row should correspond to one item in the collection.

Here's what I have so far:

---

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<%
    var items = (IQueryable<TestProj.ViewModels.TestViewModel>)Model;
        // How do I make this generic?
    var properties = items.First().GetMetadata().Properties
        .Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm));
%>
    <table>
        <tr>
<%
            foreach(var property in properties)
            {
%>
                <th>
                    <%= property.DisplayName %>
                </th>
<%
            }
%>
        </tr>
<%
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            HtmlHelper itemHtml = ????;
                // What should I put in place of "????"?
%>
            <tr>
<%
                foreach(var property in properties)
                {
%>
                    <td>
                        <%= itemHtml.Display(property.DisplayName) %>
                    </td>
<%          
                }
%>
            </tr>
<%
        }
%>
    </table>
```

---

**Two problems with this:**

1. I'd like it to be generic. So, I'd like to replace `var items = (IQueryable<TestProj.ViewModels.TestViewModel>)Model;` with `var items = (IQueryable<T>)Model;` or something to that effect.
2. A property `Html` is automatically created for me when the view is created, but this `HtmlHelper` applies to the whole collection. I need to somehow create an `itemHtml` object that applies just to the current item in the `foreach` loop. I'm not sure how to do this, however, because the constructors for `HtmlHelper` don't take a `Model` object.

How do I solve these two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phil Haack to the rescue!

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx

Answer (score 0):

for the geniric IQueryable part, why don't you simply cast it to an IQueryable...

```
var items = (IQueryable<TestProj.ViewModels.TestViewModel>)Model;
```

and What is your template for, isn't it almost the same as the default list template when you add a view... If you want to customize it, i think you'd better look for the List.tt template. You could modify that to use Html.Display instead of Html.Encode.

Or you could try using

```
Html.DisplayFor(o => property.GetValue(item))
```

I'm not sure if this would work...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm having no luck with any of the three things you suggested. If I cast as `IQueryable` instead of `IQueryable<T>`, I lose the ability to use LINQ, so `items.First()` doesn't compile. If I try just using the default `Display()` or `DisplayFor()` helper on the items, I get a blank display, even if I remove all my custom templates. As for your suggestion to try `property.GetValue()`, `GetValue()` is not even a method on `ModelMetadata` (reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata_members%28VS.100%29.aspx). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't do:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<T>>" %>
```

or even

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<T>" %>
```

ASP.NET MVC implements a Html.DisplayForModel() as Brad Wilson shows [on his blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) which does scaffolding for you out of the box. (which I'm sure you know about, mentioning for completeness).

If you look at the [MVC 2 RTM Source Code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) source code and in particular the `DefaultDisplayTemplates.cs` it's all basically contained in an HTMLHelper as suppose to a View. Perhaps instead of fighting with the auto generated class for the view (as much as I love asp.net mvc the default view rendering engine is a total pain) go with an HTMLHelper extension modelled after how ASP.NET MVC RTM implements scaffolding. I guess this would open the possibility for code reuse some more too (though almost everything is internal).

It would be nice if the ASP.NET MVC scaffolding would allow for a custom template to be passed in to change the html if you're not a fan of the default `<div class=\"display-field\">` etcetera. To me this is one of the weak spots of ASP.net MVC (the 'hardcoded' error handling/ scaffolding HTML).

If your not a fan of string building your HTML, your extension could call out to more granular partial views (like `ScaffoldCaption.ascx`) when your scaffolding HTMLHelper extension has gathered enough information to sufficiently type the granular view.

Comment: Hi Martijn, I don't mind building my own HtmlHelper method, but whether I use an .aspx file or a .cs file, I will still have the issue of how to instantiate helpers for the individual items in the collection/list. When you create a new view, that `Html` property gets populated for you. Now I need to create the equivalent object for each item in the list/collection. How do I do this? That's what the `????` is about.

Comment: Also, I wasn't able to find DefaultDisplayTemplates.cs in the source code (http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23011#).

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into the [MVCContrib Grid](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=MVCContrib&title=Grid)? Certainly someone has written an extension method to show all properties by default. If not it shouldn't be difficult.

edit2- I guess don't trust my answers on Sunday. I misread the question before and didn't realize Html.Display() was the MVC2 templated input. (I'm doing some radically different input builders at my shop so I didn't pick up on the name. I just thought Display showed the value.) Anyway, there are two options I see here.

1) Pull the MVC2 source or break out Reflector and write your own method that is not extending HtmlHelper.

2) You can use reflection here to build a new HtmlHelper instance but it's not pretty. (I didn't test this but is should work.)

```
var modelType = Html.GetType().GetGenericParameters()[0];
var itemHtmlType = typeof(HtmlHelper<>).MakeGenericType(modelType);
var itemHtmlCtor = itemHtmlType.GetConstructor(typeof(ViewContext), typeof(IViewDatacontainer), typeof(RouteCollection));
var itemHtml = itemHtmlCtor.Invoke(Html.ViewContext, Html.ViewDataContainer, Html.RouteCollection);
```

You'll get an object out of this though so you have to use reflection to invoke itemHtml.Dipslay. I'd recommend going a different route.

Comment: I'll look into the MvcContrib Grid. Thanks for the tip. As for your second answer, can you give me some idea of how to write the extension method? I mean, I know how to write extension methods in general, but I'm not clear on how I would create my own `HtmlHelper` instance with the current `item` as the model.

Comment: You could use property.GetValue(item, null) to get the value. I just prefer wrapping this kind of stuff up in a method for reuse. I guess it doesn't need to be an extension method. I wasn't thinking for a second.

Comment: But `property.GetValue(...)` is not equivalent to `Html.Display(...)`. I need something like `var itemHtml = ????`, and then I would call `itemHtml.Display(property.DisplayName)`. What should `????` be?

Comment: I edited my question a little bit. Hopefully, it is a little more clear now what I'm trying to ask.